# Hide the count of spaces left in Woocommerce Bookings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I want to remove/hide "(sinistra)" text from my WooCommerce Bookings reservations.

The site is in Italian, so "sinistra" means left.

Does anyone know what I should do?

[image]

I already tried entering this code but nothing

```php
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_slot_count_spaces_left', 25 );
function hide_slot_count_spaces_left() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('booking') ) {
        ?><style> small.booking-spaces-left{ display:none !important; }</style><?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the css code in css file so it will apply before the page load.